# Executing code after all the overrides of a virtual method

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, virtual

So I have this system set up with a base class `DisplayObject`.
It has a `Render` method and a list of other `DisplayObjects` as it's children. It also contains data about various matrix transformations but I **does not** contain the data about the actual drawing. That's why the `Render` method is virtual.

I then have 2 classes. `ColoredShape` and `TexturedShape` each inheriting from `DisplayObject` and overriding the `Render` method with a new method starting with

```
base.Render();
```

and then doing the drawing code.

What I want now is to call `Render` on all of the object's children **after** the Render on the parent has finished. So there's my problem. If I do

```
foreach (var child in Children) child.Render();
```

at the end of the `Render` method in the `DisplayObject` class it will be executed before the overrides are, since it's a part of the `base.Render()` call, and if I put that code in the subclasses instead, the `DisplayObject` alone loses that functionality and it forces all the future subclasses inheriting from it to implement the feature manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the abstract method pattern. In other words, don't make your render method virtual crate another method (virtual or abstract) that render calls., so render will look something like this:

```
public void Render()
{
    DoRender()

    foreach (var child in _children)
    {
        child.Render();
    }
}

protected virtual void DoRender()
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the code so the "render self" is separate from "render children":

```
public void Render() {
    OnRender();
    foreach(var child in Children) child.Render();
}
protected abstract void OnRender();
```

The subclasses provide `OnRender`, which renders *self*, but not the children. That is handled by `Render`. In some cases it may be useful to make `Render` as `virtual` so that the subclasses *can* control this if they need different child-behaviour.